# Работа с базой даных mySQL на пк без установленной базы даных через наш проект

Tags: java, mysql

**Короткий вопрос** интересует момент, как сделать так что-бы запустив проект созданый через Intellij IDEA Community можно было работать с добавленной в проект базой даных mySQL. Тоесть например объясните как правильно внедрить в проект базу даных mySQL что-бы польозватель без этой базы даных мог все же работать с ней через мой проект. Это например как зашить базу в проект хоть у польозвателя нету её на компьютере но он может взаимодействовать с ней через проект. Интересует как именно это сделать. Ибо я просто через File -> Project Structure добавлял в виде .jar файла connector j и все. Через мой компьютер она работает, а вот если кинуть проект на другой то не может найти этот jar файлик. Помогите очень срочно нужен ответ

Comment: джаврник добавлять не надо. ваш проект использует мавен либо градл , нужно добавить зависимость в файлы pom.xml для мавена либо build.gradle для градла. это не отменяет необходимости установки бд на компьютер (ваш джарник - всего лишь драйвер для бд, а не сама бд). драйвер последней версии здесь https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.21

Comment: @Дмитрий тоесть пользователь моего приложения обезательно должен иметь у себя на компьютере mySQL? Или как сделать все то что вы сказали например на обычном javaFx проекте без maven или gradel. Или тогда как сделать так что-бы польозватель без бд на компьютере мог её использывать? Или добавить mySQL в инсталятор, что мне необходимо сделать??

Comment: @Дмитрий помогите пожалуйсто мне понять как сделать так что-бы польозватель моего приложения мог взаимодействовать с бд без самого бд у него на компьютере, тоесть например как бы мы добавили в файлы проекта Access или другую бд, с которой мы можем работать из проекта без бд на компьютере. Или может я чего-то не понимаю... Помогите пожалуйсто мне понять. Ибо мое приложение должно постоянно инсталироватся на разные компьютеры и подрозумивать то что на кажды компьютер прийдется её ставить не подходит, как сделать так что-бы этого не делать. Испольозуя при этом простое javaFX приложение без maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ConnectorJ` - если быть точнее JDBC драйвер MySQL должен находиться в `CLASSPATH` вашего проекта
2. Это безотносительно метода сборки maven/gradle/ant и т.д. по списку (это комментарий комментарию @Дмитрий)
3. Удобнее всего весь ваш проект запаковать jar архив, в который упаковать также и `ConnectorJ` (это необязательно, но настоятельно рекомендуется).
4. Инструкция по упаковке JavaFX приложения в архив [прилагается](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html)

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ сейчас попробую разобраться, вот только а как добавить ConnectorJ в CLASSPATH? И я не особо понимаю что такое CLASSPATH, можете посоветовать где почитать

Comment: Очень странно конечно, как вы пишете целое приложение, да еще и собираетесь его распространять и не знаете что такое `CLASSPATH`... О времена, о нравы!

Comment: Из CLASSPATH я только видел на metanit как с командной строки запускать, но у меня же javaFx приложение, не совсем понимаю где найти этот CLASSPATH

Comment: Смотрите [сюда](https://itsobes.ru/JavaSobes/chto-takoe-classpath/)

Comment: Смотрите в чем проблема дело в том что сроки у меня были 6 дней на написание, и особо работать с mySQL не было времени, и сейчас я пытаюсь разобраться я толком не вьехал в тему, поэтому порошу помощи так как времени у меня уже не осталось на то что-бы сидеть и читать книгу по mySQL в будущем я это обезательно сделаю

Comment: @DevJ - как вы понимаете - это ваши проблемы :)

Comment: Ладно, в любом случаи спасибо, просто скажите после всех выше перечисленых действий можно будет обращатся к моей бд, без инсталяции mySQL пользователю себе на ПК?

Comment: Ладно, спасибо вам большое, буду что-то думать (

Comment: А classpath это разве не то когда мы в intellij IDEA добавляем библиотеку .jar в структуру проекта?

Comment: classpath это параметр конфигурации jvm, который задает, где jvm ищет классы. Задается либо как переменная окружения, либо как параметр командной строки для программы java. IDE скрывает от вас манипуляции с classpath, в данном случае, когда в IDE добавляете библиотеку, то IDE при запуске вашей программы добавляет эту библиотеку в classpath.

Comment: @RomanKonoval спасибо большое за ваш ответ